# Compute Hamming Distance

Tags: java, object-oriented

How can I make this code snippet better? Those `for` loops in `if` don't please me but they are covered with code lines that is dependent to `if` before and after.

```
public int hammingDistance(int x, int y) {
    String binx = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
    String biny = Integer.toBinaryString(y);

    int dif = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (binx.length() > biny.length()) {
        dif = binx.length() - biny.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < dif; i++) {
            sb.append(0);      
        }

        biny = sb.toString().concat(biny);
    } else if (biny.length() > binx.length()) {
        dif = biny.length() - binx.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < dif; i++) {
            sb.append(0);      
        }

        binx = sb.toString().concat(binx);
    }

    int dist = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < binx.length(); i++) {
        if (binx.charAt(i) != biny.charAt(i)) {
            dist++;
        }    
    }

    return dist;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a big simplification.  The hamming distance is the count of ones in `x^y`, so simply perform that xor and count the set bits.  There should be no need to convert to string.

Comment: Good answer but for OP this is probably kicking the can down the road: how do you count the set bits? (OK, Java has a builtin method for that … but still.)

Comment: Yes, there are various [methods to count the set bits](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive).  Which one to choose may well depend on the application domain.

Comment: Yeah, but just using `Integer.bitCount(x ^ y)` is probably more readable. Not stringifying the key is probably be biggest lesson to learn though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm agree with @TobySpeight's [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236838/203649) so I only focus on refactoring your `if else` code:

> ```
> String binx = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
> String biny = Integer.toBinaryString(y);
> int dif = 0;
> StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
> if (binx.length() > biny.length()) {
>     dif = binx.length() - biny.length();
>     for (int i = 0; i < dif; i++) {
>           sb.append(0);      
>     }
>     biny = sb.toString().concat(biny);
> } else if (biny.length() > binx.length()) {
>        dif = biny.length() - binx.length();
>        for (int i = 0; i < dif; i++) {
>             sb.append(0);      
>        }
>        binx = sb.toString().concat(binx);
> }
> ```

You can store the two String in one array and use them by index:

```
String[] bins =  { Integer.toBinaryString(x), Integer.toBinaryString(y) };
int[] lengths =  { bin[0].length(), bin[1].length() };
```

This can be simplified noting that the same block will be executed in both branchs if the absolute difference between `binx` and `biny` is not 0 so you can calculate `abs` of difference rewriting the block like below:

```
int dif = lengths[0] - lengths[1];
if (Math.abs(dif) != 0) {
    String s = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(dif, "0"));
    int i = dif > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    bins[i] = s + bins[i];
}
```

I used `String.join` and `Collections.ncopies` methods to obtain a string composed by n '0' chars.

Below the complete code of the method:

```
public static int hammingDistance(int x, int y) {
    String[] bins =  { Integer.toBinaryString(x), Integer.toBinaryString(y) };
    int[] lengths =  { bins[0].length(), bins[1].length() };

    int dif = lengths[0] - lengths[1];
    if (Math.abs(dif) != 0) {
        String s = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(dif, "0"));
        int i = dif > 0 ? 1 : 0;
        bins[i] = s + bins[i];
    }

    int dist = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lengths[0]; ++i) {
        if (bins[0].charAt(i) != bins[1].charAt(i)) {
            ++dist;
        }    
    }

    return dist;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have suggestion for you.

1. I suggest that you extract the length of the `binx` and `biny` in two variables, so you can use them instead of recalling the `java.lang.String#length` each time.

```java
String binx = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
int binxLength = binx.length();
String biny = Integer.toBinaryString(y);
int binyLength = biny.length();

//[...]
if (binxLength > binyLength) {
   //[...]
}
//[...]
```

2. You can use the method `java.lang.String#repeat` (java 11+) to repeat the zeros

```java
  sb.append("0".repeat(dif));
```

3. I suggest that you make a method to repeat the zeros.

```java
private String repeatZeros(int nb) {
   return "0".repeat(nb);
}
```

4. In my opinion, the `dif` variable is useless, you can inline it.

```java
sb.append(repeatZeros(binxLength - binyLength));
```

5. Since you are not concatenating the `String` in a loop, instead of using the `StringBuilder`, you can concat them directly.

```java
if (binxLength > binyLength) {
   biny = repeatZeros(binxLength - binyLength) + biny;
} else if (binyLength > binxLength) {
   binx = repeatZeros(binyLength - binxLength) + binx;
}
```

6. I suggest that you create a method to pad the binary string.

```java
private String padLeftWithZeros(String str, int length) {
   return repeatZeros(length) + str;
}

public int hammingDistance(int x, int y) {
   //[...]
   if (binxLength > binyLength) {
      biny = padLeftWithZeros(biny, (binxLength - binyLength));
   } else if (binyLength > binxLength) {
      binx = padLeftWithZeros(binx, (binyLength - binxLength));
   }
   //[...]
}
```

6. I suggest that you extract the distance in a method and return the result.

```java
public int hammingDistance(int x, int y) {
   //[...]
   return calculateHammingDistance(binx, binxLength, biny);
}

private int calculateHammingDistance(String binx, int binxLength, String biny) {
   int dist = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < binxLength; i++) {
      if (binx.charAt(i) != biny.charAt(i)) {
         dist++;
      }
   }

   return dist;
}
```

#### Refactored code

```java
public int hammingDistance(int x, int y) {
   String binx = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
   int binxLength = binx.length();
   String biny = Integer.toBinaryString(y);
   int binyLength = biny.length();

   if (binxLength > binyLength) {
      biny = padLeftWithZeros(biny, (binxLength - binyLength));
   } else if (binyLength > binxLength) {
      binx = padLeftWithZeros(binx, (binyLength - binxLength));
   }

   return calculateHammingDistance(binx, binxLength, biny);
}

private String padLeftWithZeros(String str, int length) {
   return repeatZeros(length) + str;
}

private String repeatZeros(int nb) {
   return "0".repeat(nb);
}

private int calculateHammingDistance(String binx, int binxLength, String biny) {
   int dist = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < binxLength; i++) {
      if (binx.charAt(i) != biny.charAt(i)) {
         dist++;
      }
   }

   return dist;
}
```